# remove specific lines if some specific word is found

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say I have a text file that contains following words

```
a
b
c
d
e>
f
g
h
I>
j
```

whenever I find a words that contains `>`, I would like to replace the last two lines from it and itself too.

For example, the output would be this.

```
a
b
f
j
```

Is it possible to achieve this ?. For simple replace, I can do this

```
with open ('Final.txt', 'w') as f2:
    with open('initial.txt', 'r') as f1:
        for line in f1:
            f2.write(line.replace('>', ''))
```

But I am stuck on how do I go back and delete the last two lines and also the line where the replace happen.

Comment: It's not really possible with a single read. What you could instead do, is read the file, pass the lines inclduing `>` into a set, and fill that set with the values you need for deletion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one approach using a simple iteration and list slicing.

**Ex:**

```
res = []
with open('initial.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if ">" in line:
            res = res[:-2]
        else:
            res.append(line)

with open('Final.txt', "w") as f2:
    for line in res:
        f2.write(line)
```

**Output:**

```
a
b
f
j
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `re`.
Here I am assuming that your data is a flat list of lines.

```
import re
print(re.sub('.*\n.*\n.*>\n','',''.join(data)))
```